# How to mask sprites in cocos2d by the alpha of a gradient?

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, mask

I'd like to make it so that a CCNode (could be CCLayer, CCSprite, etc) can mask all of its children with a shader so that they can be masked progressively as they approach the bounds of the node without having to modify their opacity value directly. For example, a menu might look like this:

[image: Menu with items that fade near the edges]

The mask in this case would be a gradient, that might look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The basic tutorial for creating a masking sprite is available at [Ray Wenderlich's website](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4428/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-2-0), though I'm not sure if it will allow you to mask children nodes as well. If not, then you'll probably have to use `CCRenderTexture`, draw children nodes to texture, then finally mask it with the masking node created in tutorial.

Comment: I've seen that tutorial, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: GoldenJoe, you cannot solve your task without render target or implementing gradient alpha into all children.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on how cocos2d does its rendering, but isn't each node just a quad with a texture? If the children render to parent nodes, then making the parent node should work. I have no idea how to do this right now, though...

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is probably not the mechanism you want, but I recently wanted a gradient alpha that varied in a circular manner.  I had some text that would rotate around a sprite and I only wanted it to be visible when it was at the top of the circle.

The simplest approach for me was to create a sprite that was a circular band where the band was a full "black" at the bottom and graduated back to fully transparent at the top.

By placing this above in the z-order, the text I then got the effect I was after.  I imagine you could achieve the same sort of effect this way

To see it in action, take a look at the main menu of my app, Claustrophobic.